# AMQ in .Net - Certificate or credentials

Tags: nms, amq, apache-nms

Should both Trust store/Key store and Certificate should be used to access AMQ Broker over SSL connection? If yes, how to achieve this? I find very less articles, blogs to do this for NMS. I am newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you only need to configure the Key Store if you are doing client authentication with the broker where the client needs to send its own key to the broker which would then have a trust store configured to validate that key.  If you are not doing mutual authentication then a client would only need a configured trust store in order to validate that the broker's key is one that it trusts.